# How to know which load copy files are being generated by current load operation

Tags: db2

I am on DB2 version 11.5.2 and I have `DB2_LOAD_COPY_NO_OVERRIDE` pointing to a local directory. How can I know which load copy files are actively being generated? I want to be able to cleanup load copy files while the load is in progress and not touch the files which are being actively used by current load operation.

```
db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11052" with level 
identifier "0603010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.2.0", "special_40112", 
"DYN2002071700AMD64_40112", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5.0.0".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns full paths of all completed `load copy` operations.

```
SELECT LOCATION
FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY
WHERE OPERATION = 'C' AND END_TIME IS NOT NULL
--AND DATE(TIMESTAMP(START_TIME)) = CURRENT DATE
;
```

Refer to the [SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022351.html) view description.